# The FAQ on daily reputation limits is a bit confusing

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination
> of the activities below. Only bounty awards and accepted answers are
> not subject to the daily reputation limit.

Out of the 7 different ways of gaining reputation listed on [the page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), the special rule for accepted answers and bounties rules out 3, leaving only:

> question is voted up: +5
>
> answer is voted up: +10
>
> suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)
>
> site association bonus: +100 on each site

But there I also feel that the site association bonus is probably excluded too (isn't it?), otherwise it's a bit discouraging to plunge into a new site, since your limit on the first day will be effectively 100.

Maybe it's a small thing, but it seems to me that instead of saying "any of the 7 combinations except 4 of them", it would be more clear to say that:

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination
> of upvotes on your questions, upvotes on your answers,
> accepted suggested edits.

Comment: From my experience [& account reputation change](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2689986/ashish-nitin-patil?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2013-11-04), yes, the `site association bonus` **is excluded**.